# How to add MomentJS to an Aurelia application

Tags: aurelia

I've got an app and I'm trying to import MomentJS to use with ValueConverting. I've gone to my package.json file and added the following to my jspm dependencies:

```
"moment": "npm:moment@^2.14.1"
```

But when I try to import it from my file, it doesn't find the module:

```
import moment from '../moment';
```

I'm trying to import it in a file that's 1 directory deep from the src folder. So, this file is in a src/folder/file.ts

How do I import moment?

Comment: This isn't an aswer, but there is discussion of this issue right now here: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/606

Comment: @AshleyGrant Does moment come built in with the starter/beginners kit?

Comment: No, it doesn't. bluebird, a fetch polyfill, bootstrap, font awesome, and jquery are the only things included in the skeletons.

Comment: @AshleyGrant Alright, thanks. The only thing we should have to do to import another package is add it to the dependencies on the package.json file and run a build, correct?

Comment: Actually, I just reread your question. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The only thing we should have to do to import another package is add
>   it to the dependencies on the package.json file and run a build,
>   correct?

You shouldn't be manually editing your package.json file like that unless absolutely necessary. You should use `jspm install moment` to get moment installed. Just adding lines to your `package.json` file doesn't actually accomplish anything.

But you've added the line to your `package.json`, and the line you added is correct, so now you need to run `jspm install` so that the code for moment can actually be pulled down and put in your project.

Next, to import moment, you'll need to do this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Now you'll have the `moment()` function ready to use in your code.

Comment: I'm working in VS2015 and I'm trying to run a jspm install on the Package Manager Console and I'm getting a "term 'jspm' is not recognized." Also, when I run a jspm install moment, it doesn't recognize that either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have jspm installed? You install it using npm `npm install -g jspm`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that may have done the trick. It's just taking forever.. How do you know when do use npm and when to use jspm?

Comment: Use npm for build dependencies, jspm for client side dependencies. We have a CLI coming soon that will make this a lot simpler. It'll use npm for both build and client dependencies, and handle the configuration and everything for you. It should eventually integrate in to Visual Studio at some point in the future.

Comment: you could also use `jspm install npm:<package>` to install npm packages via jspm

Comment: @AshleyGrant Do you know what it means when I try to run jspm install  and it gives me an error of 'Unable to load registry github. Installing changes not saved?'

I get the app to launch and serve locally, but the splash screen is the only thing that shows up. I get some errors of files not being loaded and a 'System' not defined error. Any ideas?

Comment: You might be dealing with a firewall issue. Are you able to access github.com in your web browser?

Comment: @AshleyGrant Now, in my package.json file, I don't have a systemjs dependency. Is that required?

Comment: systemjs is a dependency of jspm. You need to try running `jspm install` again. If you're on Twitter, you can follow me there, send me a tweet, and I can help you further

Comment: @AshleyGrant Just figured it out. I was trying to run jspm install -y from within VSCode and it wouldn't let me for some reason. I opened my Windows cmd prompt and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I don't personally use the VSCode command prompt, though I might in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps

1. npm install moment --save
2. typings install dt~moment --global --save
3. Add the following to the dependencies section of the aurelia.json file

   - { "name": "moment", "path": "../node_modules/moment", "main": "moment" }
4. Reference it in your .ts files with this

   - import * as moment from 'moment';

Answer (score 4):

we had the same issues using Moment in TypeScript with Aurelia.

For some reason, Moment.js installed from JSPM does not include the type definition.

Here is how I fixed it:

In config.js you must use

```
"moment": "npm:moment@2.11.2",
```

(I had issues with 2.14.1)

Then you need to find the type definition that works and add it to your `typings.json`:

"github:typed-typings/npm-moment#a4075cd50e63efbedd850f654594f293ab81a385" did the trick.

```
{
  "name": "my-cool-app-name",
    "dependencies": {
         ....
        "moment": "github:typed-typings/npm-moment#a4075cd50e63efbedd850f654594f293ab81a385"
    },
  "globalDevDependencies": {
    ........
  }
}
```

Then I would type in the cli `jspm install` and then `typings install` (jspm and typings must both be installed globally, type `npm install jspm -g` and `npm install typings -g` if that is not the case). You should now be able to import moment in your files, like so:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Hope this helps.